# Qual a diferença entre as funções streql() e strcmp() do header string.h?

Tags: c

Ambas retornam 1 se duas strings forem iguais e 0 se forem diferentes certo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcmp(s1,s2)` retorna um número negativo se s1 < s2, retorna zero se s1 = s2 e retorna um número positivo se s1 > s2.

A função streql não faz parte do padrão C e é uma extensão fornecida pelo seu compilador ou por alguma outra biblioteca que você estiver usando.